# How does ub14.04.5 FF56 successfully resolves an Internationalized Domain Name?

Tags: command-line, dns

This question because both`dig`and`nslookup`fail when FF succeeds. Is there some other command line tool that can handle IDN (I tried with double quote the DN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDN domains are translated before they're queried. The browser does this conversion.

You can install the tool `idn` to translate - `sudo apt-get install idn`.
Enter the domain you want to translate, and press enter:

```
$ idn
libidn 1.29
Copyright 2002-2014 Simon Josefsson.
GNU Libidn is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  For more
information about these matters, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
Type each input string on a line by itself, terminated by a newline character.
løk.no
xn--lk-lka.no
```

You can also specify it as a parameter:

```
$ idn løk.no
xn--lk-lka.no
```

You can also use a website tool, like https://www.punycoder.com/

The translated name can then be resolved using standard command line tools like dig or nslookup, or used in non-IDN-aware applications.

You can also pipe this straight into nslookup:

```
$ idn løk.no | nslookup
Server:         10.1.12.15
Address:        10.1.12.15#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   xn--lk-lka.no
Address: 212.125.204.196
```